# Submit not working after clicking an button element in html

Tags: php, html

I am new in web development so please understand me.

After I click the button to submit in PHP in HTML it only reloads my login.html

Can someone help me to redirect the login page into index page if the credentials of the user is correct.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
 <?php include('php/pLogin.php'); ?>
 <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="login-form-head">
                    <h4>Sign In</h4>
                    <p>Hello there, Sign in and start managing your Admin 
                    Template</p>
                </div>
                <div class="login-form-body">
                    <div class="form-gp">
                        <label for="txtUser">Email address</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtUser" name="txtUser">
                        <i class="ti-email"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-gp">
                        <label for="txtPass">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="txtPass" name="txtPass">
                        <i class="ti-lock"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-4 rmber-area">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlAutosizing">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlAutosizing">Remember Me</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 text-right">
                            <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submit-btn-area">
                        <button id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Submit">Login <i class="ti-arrow-right"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-footer text-center mt-5">
                        <p class="text-muted">Don't have an account? <a href="register.html">Sign up</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

PHP: Login.php

```
<?php
    include("pConfig.php");
    session_start();
    if($_POST['txtUser'] != '' && $_POST['txtPass'] !='') {
        $error = '';
        // username and password sent from form 
        echo $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtUser']);
        echo $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['txtPass']); 
        //$sql = "SELECT user_id  FROM user WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE (UserName = '$myusername' OR Email = '$myusername' ) and Password = '$mypassword'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count == 1) {
            //prevent session fixation attack
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername; 
            header("Location: index.html");
        } else {
            $error = 'Incorrect UserName Or Password, Please Check your Credentials';
        }
    }
?>
```

Config.php

```
<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'ci');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the action attribute in your form is empty

```
action=""
```

you need to point it your php file like this:

```
action="/path/to/your/file.php"
```

If the action attribute is empty,it will point to/refresh the file that contains the form.